# GALAXY TAB A PASSWORD RESET

Tags: recovery-mode

Holding the volume key then pressing the home on button does not work 
Whether you hold the volume up or the volume down 
Holding the Home Power Button Letting It Go And continue to hold the volume key up or down does not work

Comment: Which model is that? When you need help, always make sure all relevant informations are given this is for helping people willing to help you understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Volume up, home and power should do the trick. It sometimes is a bit tricky though. Make sure;

1. Turn **off** the device
2. Press volume up and hold, **afterwards** press home, **afterwards** press power and keep holding them
3. You should be in recovery